# Use CSS to target an element that has a duplicate class

Tags: html, css, svg, css-selectors

In my HTML, I have 2 lines that have the same class. I want to be able to target just the first element, but can't seem to figure it out. I am able to target both elements, but when I change the CSS to select the first child, it doesn't return anything.

Here is the CSS and the duplicate classes
[image]

If I use `svg g.highcharts-axis-labels`, it will select both elements.

I tried selecting the first child like below, but its not returning any elements with that CSS.

```
svg g.highcharts-axis-labels:nth-child(1)
```

Can someone point out the mistake I am making.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You want `nth-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
.highcharts-axis-labels:nth-of-type(2) {

}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: What does type in `nth-of-type` mean?

Comment: from the link in my answer: The :nth-of-type(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot you will notice that the first .highcharts-axis-labels is of type g which means the desired element is the seventh-of-type.

Comment: This answer wrong and misleading. @SalmanA's suggestion would work (`:nth-of-type(7)`).  But it should be clear that the selector given in this answer will not select what is asked for in the question. I'm guessing the answer was accepted because it got the asker on the right path.

Comment: @pep - You are correct. I accepted the answer because using nth-of-type was the correct path to take. I gave SalmanA's suggestion an up vote, because it stated to use 7 instead of 2.

Comment: @jgubbels: If you wanted a purist answer, then that answer is "there is no solution". There is no pseudo-class for the first element matching some arbitrary selector. Both answers only work by accident given the constraints in the markup.

Comment: Hard-wiring the number 7 into your code is a horrible, horrible solution. But it is also not true that "there is no solution". As given in another answer (which should be the accepted one), although there is no pseudo-class for the first element matching some arbitrary selection, you can select subsequent matching elements using the sibling selector and "turn off" the styling for those.

Answer (score 3):

`.highcharts-axis-labels` follows the element with `.highcharts-data-labels` class. So you can write:

```
.highcharts-data-labels + .highcharts-axis-labels {}
```

To target the first one.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that shows an understanding of these selectors & pseudo-classes.

Comment: You mean the second one? `+` matches for the right hand side. (sorry for necro)

Answer (score 1):

So, for your question why "its not returning any elements with that CSS".
According to the definition

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth
>   child, **regardless of type**, of its parent.

With this selector and your html,

> svg g.highcharts-axis-labels:nth-child(1)

the parent is "svg", the child is to be a "g.highcharts-axis-labels" at position 1 (in the list of all children under "svg" tag).
But the child at position 1 is not a "g.highcharts-axis-labels". Therefore the result is "no element".

Answer (score -1):

`.highcharts-axis-labels:nth-of-type(1)` should select the first element.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot you will notice that the first `.highcharts-axis-labels` is of type `g` which means the desired element is the seventh-of-type. Hardcoding `7` might not be practical.

Comment: Nice pickup, I hadn't noticed that.